# Parameter decorators with Babel (like in Typescript)

Tags: parameters, babeljs, decorator, ecmascript-next

is there way to use parameter decorators with **Babel** as it is possible in **Typescript**.

sample of a typescript code:

```
class A {
   constructor(@Inject('IService') private service: IService) {

   }
}
```

I want to write this code with **Babel**:

```
class A {
   constructor(@Inject('IService') service) {
      this.service = service;
   }
}
```

I haven't found any info on this question yet. Is there like a plugin in a certain preset that does exactly this?

If there's not way to do that without crutches, is there way to use decorators on constructors ? Example

```
class A {
   @Inject('IService')
   constructor(service) {
      this.service = service;
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is the decorator transform: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/ . But do you really need it? Depending on how it’s supposed to work, why not just write `this.service = getIService()` in the constructor?

Comment: I agree. Using decorators for this seems to make it drammatically more complicated.

Comment: I posted the question to understand if it's possible, not for reviews on how it looks. Thanks.

Comment: I hope they get to make this work in ES7, it comes in really handy for injects and other utilities.

Regarding the last question, I guess you can do the following https://jsfiddle.net/mm52n6se/

Answer (score 0):

[Babel does not currently support this feature](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9838)

You now have two options:

- use babel-plugin-parameter-decorator instead
- use tsc

Unfortunately, the first option is not perfect in detail, as the following example illustrates:

```js
@Get('/:id')
getUser(@Param("id") id: number) {
  cosnole.log(typeof id); // string
}
```